# two image inside a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf

here is my problem. i have two image inside a scrollviewer.

but i can't make it work because:

```
it says the property content can only be set once.
```

is there a workaround to make it work?

i need to overlay two image inside scrollviewer.

one of the image control opacity is set to 50%

one of the image control in on the top. in order to overlay

and i need the scrollviewer in order to view the picture when the image cotrol stretch property is set to none.

Comment: There are too many possible answers to your question. They will all essentially involve making the immediate child of your `ScrollViewer` object some kind of container itself, into which you put the two images. But without more specifics about your need, it's impossible to know exactly what you should do. Please explore the available options for containers, and if you still wind up with a problem, post a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, with an explanation of what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a grid within the scroll viewer and then put both images inside the grid.

Comment: make sure you set the Z-Index appropriately.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2006/06/13/controlling-z-order-using-the-zindex-property/